# how should i write this program on python?

Tags: python

can you please tell me why do i get error for this?
Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num=input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 'done':
            break
        num=int(num)
        if largest == None or largest<num:
            largest = num
        elif smallest == None or smallest > num:
            smallest = num
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid input")
        break
print ("Maximum number is", int(largest))
print ("Minimum number is", int(smallest))
```

Comment: "why do i get error"—What error? Please post the stack trace

Comment: Please include the error you're getting, along with what input you're using to get the error.

Comment: Make sure both largest and smallest are set to an integer instead of their default of `None`. If you continuously enter larger numbers, `smallest` will never be set and be `None`, which can't be converted to an integer (last code line).

Comment: Try changing the `elif` to an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using Python 2 instead of Python 3 - please check this. If you are using Python 2, you should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `largest` or `smallest` `is None`.
Append the user input to a list inside the while loop, and then slice it in the final print statements:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
nums = []
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 'done':
            break
        num = int(num)
        nums.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        break

print("Maximum number is", max(nums))
print("Minimum number is", min(nums))
```

Example run:

```
Enter a number: 22
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: done
Maximum number is 22
Minimum number is 2
```

Comment: The OP is already doing that, just using `==` instead of `is`, but that's not a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Change `elif` to `if`:

```
    if largest == None or largest<num:
        largest = num
    if smallest == None or smallest > num:
        smallest = num
```

That will guarantee both `largest` and `smallest` are both integers (unless the first input is `done` or another invalid value).

Answer (score 0):

Posting the output and/or the error would be very helpful to help you.

You have to change `elif` into `if` and remove the `break` clause inside the `except` in order to keep asking for numbers even after an invalid input.

```py
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    try:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 'done':
            break
        num=int(num)
        if largest == None or largest < num:
            largest = num
        if smallest == None or smallest > num:
            smallest = num
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid input")
print ("Maximum number is", int(largest))
print ("Minimum number is", int(smallest))
```